# MongoDB commands from DOS or Windows

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to copy 4 collections from one Mongo database to another on the same machine from C# program automatically. How do I do that? Is there a simple copy collection/database command in MongoDB C# driver? or do I have to use the Mongo shell by first typing the `./mongo`? If so how do I do that inside a MS-DOS command line window? Like `./mongo -copycollection from to`?

Comment: Check you have mongodb installed. If you navigate to the folder where it's installed you can open a terminal there and use the mongodump commands.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use mongodump, Type:

```
./mongodump --db your_db_name --collection collection_name
```

and then mongorestore:

```
./mongorestore --db=new_db_name
```

Read more: [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodump/)  and [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongorestore/)

Answer (score 14):

you can use [mongodump & mongorestore](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-DataImportandExport)

1-> back up a single database
`mongodump -h localhost -d database_name -o C:\DestinationFolder` (backup to a DestinationFolder )

2-> Restore the Database

`mongorestore -h localhost C:\DestinationFolder`  (Restor from the DestinationFolder )

**or**

3-> you ca backup and restor a single collection at a time

back up a single collection

```
mongodump -h localhost -d database_name -c Collection_name -o C:\Dest_SingleCollBkp
```

4->Restore a single Collection

```
mongorestore -h localhost C:\Dest_SingleCollBkp
```

**or**

5-> you can copy a single collection at the time

copy ->

```
use source_database;
var docs = db.source_collection.find({ accessed: {
       '$gte': new Date(2012, 4, 1), '$lt': new Date(2012, 5, 1)
         } });
```

past -> :)

```
use new_database;
//switched to db new_database
 docs.forEach(function(doc) { db.new_collection.insert(doc) });
```

6-> [copy the entire database](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Copy+Database+Commands)

```
db.copyDatabase('from_database_name', 'to_databasename', 'from_hostname')
```

Comment: This worked for me, and to add a few simple steps, I opened command prompt in the folder where mongodump.exe resides, after mongod.exe is running, then could run the mongodump -h localhost -d database_name -o C:\DestinationFolder command and it worked.

Comment: correct! and you could always add the path to your installations and executables into the environment variables. this is a good source for how to add a new folder to my system path http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path

Comment: Hello, I am able to restore whole mongo dump, I see following error
C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>mongorestore --db DEVL D:\DB\Database Dumps
Error parsing command line: too many positional options
try 'mongorestore --help' for more information
C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>