# Unable to restore bson file to mongodb in windows machine

Tags: mongodb

I am new to `mongo` and trying to `restore/import` below `bson files` to mongo version `3.0.6`,

[image]

but when I am trying below option it's failing with following error: Please refer the screen shot. FYI - I'm running CMD as administrator.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongorestore -h localhost C:\dump\sampledb\
2016-03-22T01:01:49.266+0530    building a list of dbs and collections to restore from C:\dump\sampledb dir
2016-03-22T01:01:49.268+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\categories.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.269+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\customers.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.269+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\employee-territories.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.270+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\employees.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.271+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\order-details.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.271+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\orders.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.272+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\products.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.272+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\regions.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.273+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\shippers.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.274+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\suppliers.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.274+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.275+0530    don't know what to do with file "C:\dump\sampledb\territories.bson", skipping...
2016-03-22T01:01:49.275+0530    done

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>
```

Please guide. I've taken a help from link: [MongoDB commands from DOS or Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592305/mongodb-commands-from-dos-or-windows), but solution worked for me so far. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use below. I guarantees that this will work. I assume you're using same bson files from link: https://github.com/tmcnab/northwind-mongo

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongorestore -h localhost -d boot -o C:\dump\sampledb\
```

where: -d boot, boot is the database name. You can give any name.

FYI:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongorestore -h localhost -d boot  C:\dump\sampledb\
2016-03-22T01:10:08.999+0530    building a list of collections to restore from C:\dump\sampledb\ dir
2016-03-22T01:10:09.000+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:09.001+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:09.016+0530    restoring boot.order-details from file C:\dump\sampledb\order-details.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:09.017+0530    restoring boot.orders from file C:\dump\sampledb\orders.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:09.018+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:09.018+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:09.036+0530    restoring boot.products from file C:\dump\sampledb\products.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:09.037+0530    restoring boot.customers from file C:\dump\sampledb\customers.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:11.713+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.customers from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:11.739+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.orders from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:11.740+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.products from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:11.766+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.order-details from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:11.824+0530    finished restoring boot.customers (91 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:11.825+0530    finished restoring boot.orders (830 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:11.825+0530    finished restoring boot.order-details (2155 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:11.825+0530    finished restoring boot.products (77 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:11.920+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:11.923+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:11.931+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:11.938+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:11.945+0530    restoring boot.employees from file C:\dump\sampledb\employees.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:11.950+0530    restoring boot.territories from file C:\dump\sampledb\territories.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:11.957+0530    restoring boot.suppliers from file C:\dump\sampledb\suppliers.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:11.960+0530    restoring boot.categories from file C:\dump\sampledb\categories.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:14.965+0530    [########################]    boot.employees  8.1 KB/8.1 KB  (100.0%)
2016-03-22T01:10:14.967+0530    [########################]  boot.territories  4.6 KB/4.6 KB  (100.0%)
2016-03-22T01:10:14.972+0530    [########################]   boot.categories  3.1 KB/3.1 KB  (100.0%)
2016-03-22T01:10:14.977+0530    [########################]    boot.suppliers  9.2 KB/9.2 KB  (100.0%)
2016-03-22T01:10:14.982+0530
2016-03-22T01:10:14.987+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.suppliers from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:14.992+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.territories from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:14.997+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.categories from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:15.001+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.employees from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:15.005+0530    finished restoring boot.suppliers (29 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:15.008+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:15.012+0530    finished restoring boot.categories (8 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:15.022+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:15.025+0530    finished restoring boot.territories (53 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:15.031+0530    no metadata file; reading indexes from C:\dump\sampledb\system.indexes.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:15.034+0530    restoring boot.employee-territories from file C:\dump\sampledb\employee-territories.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:15.042+0530    restoring boot.shippers from file C:\dump\sampledb\shippers.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:15.048+0530    finished restoring boot.employees (12 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:15.161+0530    restoring boot.regions from file C:\dump\sampledb\regions.bson
2016-03-22T01:10:15.858+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.employee-territories from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:16.462+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.shippers from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:16.466+0530    finished restoring boot.shippers (3 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:16.666+0530    restoring indexes for collection boot.regions from metadata
2016-03-22T01:10:16.670+0530    finished restoring boot.regions (4 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:17.413+0530    finished restoring boot.employee-territories (49 documents)
2016-03-22T01:10:17.416+0530    done
```